# Subscribe to an AngularFireAuth email verification event

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFireAuth (from Github/angularfire2) to connect with Firebase. Is it possible to get an event when the auth state changes due to a change in the backend? For example user verified his email. I have a subscription on the auth state:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((authState: User) => {
       // this should invoke when user verify email.
       // it invokes when user logs in with Facebook, for e.g
       console.log("User verified!");
     })
  }
}
```

Just for context, I don't let users to access the app without confirming their emails. If I don't get the event, the user has to refresh the page on their own (after email verification).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this.

In fact, this exact feature was requested late last year but it was closed without reason. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1334